# XCode 8.1 (8B62) - not able to build app on iPad Retina (ipad 4)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, retina

Recently I upgraded my Xcode to 8.1 (8B63) and migrated the 7.3.4 project successfully. Tested on simulators and was able to build on iPad Retina (iPad 4) simulator with deployment target 8.4. But when I connected my device (iPad 4), I got the following error:

Could not locate device support files.
This iPad (4th generation Model A1458) is running iOS 10.2.1 (14D27), which may not be supported by this version of XCode.

I am not able to understand why - as the project can work on iPad 4 simulator, but not able to connect to the device. Can you please help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Xcode again. I have this same problem sometimes when I update my iDevice right when Apple pushes an update to iOS. The problem is that your device's iOS is *too current*, and your Xcode actually doesn't recognize it (it's outdated - the latest is 8.2.1 I believe).

If you're an Apple Developer with a current account, you can actually see the latest version of Xcode (and beta versions) here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=xcode  Also you can bypass the annoying time-outs and bugs you sometimes will experience downloading Xcode through the AppStore

I think Xcode 8.2.1 should help, if not - try Xcode 8.3 Beta (if it's available)

Comment: Thanks. It helped. Looks like 8.2.1 has many fixes. Appreciate your help.